# What is the best way to count rows in a mySQL complex table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields (for example);

id, reference, customerId.

Now, I often want to log an enquiry for a customer.. BUT, in some cases, I need to filter the enquiry based on the customers country... which is in the customer table..

id, Name, Country..for example

At the moment, my application shows 15 enquiries per page and I am SELECTing all enquiries, and for each one, checking the country field in customerTable based on the customerId to filter the country. I would also count the number of enquiries this way to find out the total number of enquiries and be able to display the page (Page 1 of 4).

As the database is growing, I am starting to notice a bit of lag, and I think my methodology is a bit flawed!

My first guess at how this should be done, is I can add the country to the enquiryTable. Problem solved, but does anyone else have a suggestion as to how this might be done? Because I don't like the idea of having to update each enquiry every time the country of a contact is changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your SQL. You can probably accomplish what you want with a simple `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE`, but without seeing your data definitions and SQL, it's hard to say. The answer is almost surely NOT adding a `country` column to the inquiry table, though.

Comment: That should do the trick, thanks! Is this efficient, and How can I count the number of of rows.. Im guessing it would just be SELECT count(*) ..INNER JOIN CODE...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this data should be spread over 3 tables

customers
enquiries
countries

Then by using joins you can bring out the customer and country data and filter by either.  Something like.....

```
SELECT 
enquiries.enquiryid,
enquiries.enquiredetails,
customers.customerid,
customers.reference,
customers.countryid,
countries.name AS countryname
FROM
enquiries
INNER JOIN customers ON enquiries.customerid = customers.customerid
INNER JOIN countries ON customers.countryid = countries.countryid
WHERE countries.name='United Kingdom'
```

You should definitely be only touching the database once to do this.

Depending on how you are accessing your data you may be able to get a row count without issuing a second COUNT(*) query.  You havent mentioned what programming language or data access strategy you have so difficult to be more helpful with the count.  If you have no easy way of determining row count from within the data access layer of your code then you could use a stored procedure with an output parameter to give you the row count without making two round trips to the database.  It all depends on your architecture, data access strategy and how close you are to your database.

Comment: PS.  I guessed at table names but you should get the idea. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for a great answer! I understand now what I have to do.. I am using PHP at the moment, and I am building my own data models, (No framework for me, although I probably should). This particular function is as you have probably guessed, a filter function, that I call to get all the Ids of the enquiries that fit my filter.. I then go through each ID, and initiate an enquiry class,( which might be bad practice) and then print them in a table

Comment: Looping through the rows and populating your own business objects is a perfectly valid way of doing this.  If you don't need any more help can you please mark this as an answer.  Ta